# How to reference unittest TestClass attribute in @patch decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I want to make use of my tempfile module to write files in my test case.
But I am having trouble referencing it when usinng mock.patch

Supposed I have this code, notice the patch as it is referencing the self.test_dir

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import tempfile

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.test_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()

    def tearDown(self):
        # Close the file, the directory will be removed after the test
        self.test_dir.cleanup()

    @patch("sample_module.SampleClass.base_url", self.test_dir)
    def test_override(self):
        pass
```

Running this code will result to this error

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

As the test_dir is being initialized in the setup and tearDown method then how can I make use of this tempfile.TemporaryDirectory

Any thoughts?

Comment: `patch` decorator function called when method defined, so you cannot pass instance at that time(There is no instance yet). You may make `test_dir` attribute as **static** attribute if you could(I don't know your TemporaryDirectory's logic).

Comment: I wanted the automatic handling of this temporarydirectory so I place it in the setUp and tearDown method of the unittest.TestCase so that it will be cleaned up automatically.  I am looking of alternative way of doing this as I need to override something